# How can SUSER_SNAME return the localized user name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, logins

I need to assign network service user to SQL Server database programmatically, so I am running this script:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

DECLARE @user nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @SQLStatement nvarchar(500)
SET @user = SUSER_SNAME(0x010100000000000514000000);
SET @SQLStatement =
N'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT principal_id FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = ''' + @user + ''')
  BEGIN
      CREATE USER ' + quotename(@user) + ' FOR LOGIN ' + quotename(@user) + N' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
      ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER ' + quotename(@user) + '
  END'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStatement;
GO
```

That does not work. The problem is that, when running

`PRINT SUSER_SNAME(0x010100000000000514000000)`

This is returned:

`NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`

That is wrong, since my system is in Spanish. When I add that user manually using SQL Server Manager and then I see the users in the database, that user is actually added as:

`NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de red`

Is there a way to add Network service account independent of language?

Comment: Do you get an actual error? I don't think SQL Server keeps track of localisations of windows logins. It just associates their SID, and lets the OS do it's thing. From SQL Servers point of view. It doesn't matter whether it's in Italian, Spanish, German or English.

Comment: @DKramer it seems it does matter. When that user is not already in the database, it is created as `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` which is wrong. When I add it using SQL Server Manager, the added user is `NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de Red`. If that user already exist, the error is 
`The login already has an account with another username.`. On the other hand, since the added user is `NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de Red`, that IF statement always evaluates to TRUE.

Comment: Your script works for me on a German installation where `@user` is returned as `NT-AUTORITÄT\Netzwerkdienst`. Strange.

Comment: @Johnakahot2use Yes... it worked in my PC before... in customer's PC also.... but after some Windows 10 update, it stopped working in my PC. The rule is: if in my PC stopped working, it is more likely that in customer's PC will not work also. That's why I need this to be not language dependent,

Comment: Can you tag for SQL Server version? I'm sure of the exact terminology, but what are the "regional settings" of the user that the script is running as?

Comment: Have you confirmed your local PC's regional settings are currently set as expected?  This can be found via System Settings -> Time & Language -> Region (or just type *Region* into the Windows search bar)  I suspect this is local to your system due to a configuration setting.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the SID — a value that does not change based on culture — you might as well use it:

```sql
DECLARE @Login sysname,
        @DelimitedLogin NVARCHAR(258),
        @SID VARBINARY(85);

SET @SID = 0x010100000000000514000000;

SELECT @Login = sp.[name]
FROM   sys.server_principals sp
WHERE  sp.[sid] = @SID;

SET @DelimitedLogin =  QUOTENAME(@Login);

IF (NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM   sys.database_principals dp
        WHERE  dp.[sid] = @SID
              )
    AND @Login IS NOT NULL
   )
BEGIN
  EXEC(N'
CREATE USER ' + @DelimitedLogin + N' FOR LOGIN ' + @DelimitedLogin
  + N' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo];
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER ' + @DelimitedLogin + N';
');
END;
GO
```